# character not stored as NULL in database

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using mysql2 adapter in rails 3.0.20.
    I have a column name as 'city' & the data type of the 'city' is 'string'.
    ":patient_details, :city, :string, :null => true"
    I didn't enter any data in the 'city' text field and save it.
    In database, it shows as an empty string "" and not as a NULL.
    Why it store like this?
    How can i store it as a NULL character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some code (something like the following) before saving the model to database. When rails receives data from the front-end, it may not be able to distinguish empty data or null data.

```
patient_details.city = nil if patient_details.city == ''
```

BTW, I wouldn't use nullable data for database columns unless it is really, really necessary.

Comment: Is there any way to set default value from database side??

Comment: @Vicky It has nothing to do with the database default value. Rails captured the empty string passed from the front-end, assign it to your model, and store it into database. So, what database receives is a field with empty string, not nothing. You can set the default value in your application logic. Maybe in the [`before_save`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback.